# A Wordpress shortcode keeps on popping up as text in my Wordpress content

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've been migrating an old Wordpress site of mine and doing some theme work in order to refresh it and optimize for site speed.

I've noticed that ever since I switched to the theme Longform, there have been a bunch of errors. Most of the formatting/alignment stuff I'm slowly fixing through the use of a child theme but there's this one problem that keeps on frustrating me: a shortcode, [ssba] can be consistently found in the HTML output.

I can't target this output by CSS, and I'm not sure where it's loading from. Any help would be greatly appreciated: maybe I'm just brain-farting but I can't seem to figure this out.

The screenshot is below (I don't have enough rep to embed it), and a live example can be seen at the bottom of http://code-love.com/2014/06/21/startups-can-truly-change-world/.

[image]

Comment: did you check your post.php template, it seems to have been added right after the entry-meta and before the author-info, does your theme supports hooking on that area?

Comment: Finally figured it out. There was a page called single.php that defined post templates (instead of the standard post.php). Once I looked inside, I saw there was an IF function that echoed the shortcode--assumably there's something funky in the back-end, but for now I've commented out the offending piece of code. All is good :) Thanks for reaching out silver!

Comment: it was actually single.php that is use for post template and not post.php, my mind just messed things up lol and glad you've figured it out ;)